# How can you force weights of different layers to be equal in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is there a way to force the weights of different layers to be equal during the training of a model in Keras?
To be more clear, if I have a model with 5 layers like so:

```
inputlayer = Dense(units=40, activation='relu', input_dim=20)
hidden1 = Dense(units=40, activation='relu')(inputlayer)
hidden2 = Dense(units=5,activation='relu')(hidden1)
hidden3 = Dense(units=40,activation='relu')(hidden2)
hidden4 = Dense(unites=40,activation='relu')(hidden3)
outputlayer = Dense(units=20,activation='relu')(hidden4)
```

I would like it so that inputlayer and outputlayer have their weights tied, the same for hidden1 and hidden4, and hidden2 and hidden3. I realize their dimensions are different, i.e input layer is(20,40) while outputlayer is (40,20), so I need a way to instantiate the layers so that their weights are tied but transposed as well. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: You should read this part of the documentation:
https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#shared-layers

Comment: Matias' answer solves the problem. But wonder why would you ever want to do that? The purpose of using multi-layer networks is to learn different level of abstraction/representation. By fixing the weights of the layers, I think it'll be no better than single-layer one.

Comment: The reason I would like to do this is I am building a model where I want the input and output layers to have their weights tied and the 2 outer hidden layers to have their weights tied. The dimensions will not be the same but probably transposed. For e.g the input layer may have input_dim = 20 and 80 nodes, where as the output layer has output dim=20 and also 80 nodes. Is it possible to tie their weights in this case?

Comment: I will edit my question to make it more clear what I would like to do.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite easy for the functional API, you just have to do:

```
layer = Dense(units=40, activation='relu', name="one")
n1 = layer(someInput)
n2 = layer(someOtherInput)
```

You make one instance of the layer and just give it two different inputs. As you call the layer two times, both instances have the same weights.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to make a model that will have 5 layers. I want the input and output layers to have their weights tied and the 2 outer hidden layers to have their weights tied. How can I do this with the code you have given?

Comment: Say I want to create *two* layers, where the weights in one layer are the transpose of the weights in the other layer. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

With custom layer. Tensorflow version 2.11.0 example follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


class TransposedDense(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, original_layer):
        super().__init__()
        self.original_layer = original_layer
    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul( inputs, self.original_layer.weights[0], transpose_b=True)

inputlayer = keras.Input(shape=(3,))
l1 = keras.layers.Dense(units=2, kernel_initializer="zeros", use_bias=False)
middlelayer = l1( inputlayer )
l2 = TransposedDense( l1 )
outputlayer = l2(middlelayer)
model = keras.Model(inputlayer, outputlayer)
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 3)]               0         
                                                             
 dense (Dense)               (None, 2)                 6         
                                                             
 transposed_dense (Transpose  (None, 3)                6         
 dDense)                                                         
                                                             
=================================================================
Total params: 6
Trainable params: 6
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Change the weights:

```
simplemarix=tf.convert_to_tensor(
    [[1,2],
     [11, 12],
     [21, 22]],
    dtype='float32'
    )
model.layers[1].set_weights( [ simplemarix ] )
# we changed the first, and the second is also changing
model.layers[2].weights
```

Output:

```
[<tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(3, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[ 1.,  2.],
        [11., 12.],
        [21., 22.]], dtype=float32)>]
```

Evaluate this  model:

```
# test input: batchsize of 1, shape=(1,3)
test_input = tf.convert_to_tensor( 
    [[1., 0., 0.]])
model( test_input )
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[ 5., 35., 65.]], dtype=float32)>
```